# React странный вывод в консоль в начале работы приложения

Tags: reactjs, webpack, npm, create-react-app

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
```

Именно это выводит в консоль приложение ссылаясь на файл `/log.js:24` (Лежит в `node_modules/webpack`)

Я пытался закоментировать эту строчку и весь файл, но без результата.
Проблема появилась как только создал новое приложение (`create-react-app`) Раньше такого не было

Версия *React* `6.13.4`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это проблема webpack. Вы можете убрать это, выполнив следующие действия:

1. Перейти в `node_modules -> webpack -> hot folder`
2. Тут вы найдете файл `log.js`, откройте его
3. Закомментируйте строку вывода в консоль в разделе `if(level === "info")`

Блок кода, который вам нужен:

```
module.exports = function(level, msg) {
    if (shouldLog(level)) {
        if (level === "info") {
            // console.log(msg);
        } else if (level === "warning") {
            console.warn(msg);
        } else if (level === "error") {
            console.error(msg);
        }
    }
};
```

Ссылки на источники:

- [[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...`is not affected by`clientLogLevel: 'silent'](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2166)
- [HMR not working and logging "Waiting for update signal from WDS"](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2154)
- [[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS... in console](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8153)

Какой файл необходимо отредактировать - можно увидеть в консоли браузера. Если закомментированная строка не решает проблему, пробуйте изменить версию `react-scripts` при создании приложения:

```
npx create-react-app project-name --scripts-version 3.2.0
```

Comment: if (level === "info") с пробелом после `if` - работает